# Python Tkinter program to return text from given url

Tags: python, tkinter, label, urllib

I'm having some trouble doing what I thought wouldn't be too difficult. I want to create a program that uses a given DOI (unique identification for research papers) and sends it to a website, returning the Bibtex formatted text result to the user such that they can select, copy and paste the result.

The (Python 3.x) code below is my attempt (first time with Tkinter and class programming in Python), though I can't seem to get the label to be able to update as I'd expect it to. You might also notice I don't really understand the use of 'self', but that's a separate question for another time. If you want to jazz it up a bit feel free!

Thanks.

```
import urllib.request
from tkinter import *

##This is the logic of what I want to do
# x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.crossref.org/works/10.1098/rsta.2010.0348/transform/application/x-bibtex')
# data = x.read()
# print(data)

'''Small attempt at a program to take a DOI input (unique address for research papers) and 
    return the Bibtex formatted result from the above website in a copy/pastable form. 
    It should handle HTTP errors and be reusable. While the program below is my attempt,
    any solution that does the above would be appreciated.'''

class MyFirstGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("DOI to Bibtex Tool")

        self.label1 = Label(master, text="Enter DOI")

        ##Give a default, customisable DOI value
        self.v = StringVar(root, value='10.1098/rsta.2010.0348')
        self.entry1 = Entry(master, bd =5, textvariable=self.v)
        self.label1.pack()
        self.entry1.pack()

        self.submit = Button(master, text ="Submit", command = self.update)
        self.submit.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

        ##Here I want to produce the result of my http request call
        self.v = StringVar()
        self.v.set("Output area for result of HTTP request to be updated when you press submit\n"
                                        +"(ideally highlightable/copy pastable)")
        self.output_label = Label(master, text=self.v.get())
        self.output_label.pack()


        ##This here is an experimental method to get highlightable text, which is desirable but can't get this to work either.
        #Uncomment for example
        # self.w = Text(master, height=100)
        # self.w.insert(1.0, self.v.get())
        # self.w.pack()
        # self.w.configure(bg=self.master.cget('bg'), relief=FLAT)
        # self.w.configure(state="disabled")


    def update(self):
        doi = str(self.entry1.get()) ##Get the user inputted DOI 
        print(str(self.entry1.get()))
        url = 'http://api.crossref.org/works/'+ doi + '/transform/application/x-bibtex'
        print(url)

        try:
            x = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        except urllib.error.URLError as e: 
            print(str(e))
            ##Show user an error if they put in the wrong DOI
            self.v.set(str(e)) ##This doesn't update. Something like label.update() would be nice

        else:
            ##Update the output area to the returned form of the text entry, ideally highlightable for copying
            data = x.read()
            self.v.set(data) ##This doesn't update. Something like label.update() would be nice
            print(data) ##I also want it to interpret the escape characters, so \n becomes linebreak etc


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Example output:
[image: example output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use `StringVar` to achieve what you want. 
The code below shows you how to get a copy/pastable text using a Text widget and no StringVar.

You need to switch the state of the text widget back to normal each time you want to update it so I wrote an `update_text` method to update the widget content.

```
import urllib.request
from tkinter import *


class MyFirstGUI(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        # create main window by calling the __init__ method of parent class Tk
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("600x400")
        self.title("DOI to Bibtex Tool")

        label1 = Label(self, text="Enter DOI")
        label1.pack()

        ##Give a default, customisable DOI value
        self.entry1 = Entry(self, bd=5)
        self.entry1.insert(0, '10.1098/rsta.2010.0348')
        self.entry1.pack()

        submit = Button(self, text ="Submit", command = self.update)
        submit.pack()

        close_button = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.quit)
        close_button.pack()

        ##Here I want to produce the result of my http request call
        self.w = Text(self, relief='flat', 
                      bg = self.cget('bg'),
                      highlightthickness=0, height=100) 
        # trick to make disabled text copy/pastable
        self.w.bind("<1>", lambda event: self.w.focus_set())
        self.w.insert('1.0', "Output area for result of HTTP request to be updated when you press submit\n"
                                        +"(ideally highlightable/copy pastable)")
        self.w.configure(state="disabled", inactiveselectbackground=self.w.cget("selectbackground"))
        self.w.pack()

        self.mainloop()

    def update_text(self, new_text):
        """ update the content of the text widget """
        self.w.configure(state='normal')
        self.w.delete('1.0', 'end')    # clear text
        self.w.insert('1.0', new_text) # display new text
        self.w.configure(state='disabled') 


    def update(self):
        doi = str(self.entry1.get()) ##Get the user inputted DOI 
        print(str(self.entry1.get()))
        url = 'http://api.crossref.org/works/'+ doi + '/transform/application/x-bibtex'
        print(url)

        try:
            x = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        except urllib.error.URLError as e: 
            ##Show user an error if they put in the wrong DOI
            self.update_text(str(e)) 

        else:
            ##Update the output area to the returned form of the text entry, ideally highlightable for copying
            data = x.read()
            self.update_text(data) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_gui = MyFirstGUI()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
self.output_label = Label(master, textvariable=self.v)
```

`textvariable` allows you to update the text within the label.

Comment: FWIW, you can update the text in the label without `textvariable`, too.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Yes, you are right, you can also set text via .config(): `self.output_label.config(text=data)`

Comment: Ahhhhhh that's what I needed. Any ideas on how to make the result selectable/ copy to clipboard?

Comment: @BenJones: you'll need to use an Entry or Text widget.